# Application Service code in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design

We are starting a new project and trying to implement some concepts from Domain driven design. We are planning to have following layers:

1. Web Interface (WebAPI)
2. Application Services (library)
3. Domain Services (library)
4. Data Access Services (Library)

We are thinking about merging Web interface and Application service together. So, our webAPI will be talking to repositories, domain model and domain services.

Is this fine or should we have separate project form application services and WebAPI should only communicate with Application services?

Thanks

Comment: There probably isn't anything wrong with having coarse-grained application services that act as a go-between but I tend to start off without these until I need them.  Sometimes the delegation is just too thin for me to bother with, e.g: `SomeService.Find(id)` vs. `SomeQuery.Find(id)`... not much in it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP should be seen as one of potentially many access ports to reach your application services. If you could be entirely sure that you will never have to speak to your application through another communication channel than HTTP then I'd say it's perfectly not to have a seperate application layer.

However, I'd also say that it's very hard to predict how application needs will evolve and since adding an additionnal layer of indirection to segregate the application layer right away shouldn't be very costly (it's just delegation) that's what I'd do.